# displaying Child post into Wordpress page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I Have A Custom Type Post **our-trainers** which has a post **XYZ** and **MTJ** etc.  and another post **ABC** and **TKY** etch, **XYZ** is the Parent of **ABC** and **TKY** i want to display only **ABC** and **TKY** post

like -

**XYZ**

ABC (description).

ABC_ (description).

**MTJ**

child post 1(description).

child post 2(description).

```
<?php
 /**
  * Template Name: Blog

  The template for displaying all pages.
  *
  * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
  * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
  * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
  * different template.
  *
  * @package Sydney
  */

     get_header(); 
 ?>

 <?php
              $array = array('post_type'=>'our-trainers',  'posts_per_page' => 30, 'order' => 'ASC');
              $array_query = new wp_query($array);
            while ($array_query->have_posts() ) : $array_query->the_post();
            ?>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <?php //the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php
          $array = array('post_type'=>'our-trainers', 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'order' => 'ASC');
          $array_query = new wp_query($array);
        while ($array_query->have_posts() ) : $array_query->the_post();
        ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

shows only last parents post and there child posts.

Answer (score 0):

sYou could try changing your query. In this case adding the query Key: `post_parent__in`. This should limit the Results to all `our-trainers` Post-Type that have a specific parent ID.

```
    <?php
          $array = array(
              'post_type'       => 'our-trainers', 

              // ADD THE FOLLOWING LIKE: THE ARRAY COULD BE A LIST OF IDS OR JUST 1 ID.
              'post_parent__in' => array("ID_OF_THE_POST_PARENT"), 

              'posts_per_page'  => 30, 
              'order'           => 'ASC'
          );
          $array_query = new wp_query($array);
        while ($array_query->have_posts() ) : $array_query->the_post();
           // THE REST OF THE CODE...
```

**OPTION NR 2**

```
    <?php
          $parentIDs    = array(214, 412);
          $array        = array(
              'post_type'       => 'our-trainers', 
              'posts_per_page'  => 30, 
              'order'           => 'ASC'
          );
          $array_query  = new wp_query($array);
        while ($array_query->have_posts() ) : $array_query->the_post();
           $pID         = get_the_ID();
           // GET THE POST OBJECT;
           $pOBJ        = get_post($pID);
           // CHECK IF THE PARENT ID OF THE POST IS CONTAINED IN THE LIST OF 
           // PARENT_IDS...
           if(in_array($pOBJ->parent_id, $parentIDs)){ 
              // DISPLAY ONLY THESE POSTS...
           }
           // THE REST OF THE CODE...
```

Comment: thanks. but the parent post should be dynamic means it can be increase ..

Comment: @devendra  In that case, yo need to check within the loop. That would be another way to do it....